# External JS files not running (flask)

Tags: javascript, html, flask

In layout.html, I have 4 script tags at the bottom of body tag

```
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.backstretch.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/templatemo-script.js')}}"></script>
```

Neither of them are working, however the below external css works just fine.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/templatemo-diagoona.css') }}">`

static folder contains (css, js, img)folders

Comment: Should it not be without the extra info in src just like `src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"`?

Comment: When you say "none is working," do you mean that they're not getting requested (i.e., not showing up on the flask console log), or that they're having no affect on the page?

Comment: The problem was in bootstrap files. Just had to delete /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */ from bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.js.